# Omit Argument in Controller Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm studying symfony book and I have read that I can omit the parameter in my Controller (http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/controller.html#route-parameters-as-controller-arguments)

I have tried with this configuration

my route

```
_demo:
  path:     /{lastName}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:index}
```

And My Controller

```
public function indexAction(){
    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:index.html.twig');
}
```

When I visit the Route without parameter ( lastName )

```
http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/
```

I Get this Error

```
No route found for "GET /"
```

But In symfony book I can read:

> Not all routing parameters need to be arguments on your controller
>
> If, for example, the lastName weren't important for your controller,
>   you could omit it entirely:

I'm using symfony 2.3
Thanks a Lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you don't have the route with `/`, but a route with parameter `/{param}`

if you visit

```
http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/foo
```

you Can get this route and you can omit the param in your Controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:index.html.twig');
}
```

The param is optional in your controller NOT in your route. Then if you want `/`route, you have to create a new route.

E.g

```
_demo2:
  path:     /
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:index2}
```

You can check your route with

```
php app/console router:debug
```

You can read all your routes

Answer (score -1):

In order for your route to hit the indexAction from your controller, you need to specify a default value for `lastName`:

```
_demo:
      path:     /{lastName}
      defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:index, lastName: null}
```